# SQL for getting top user based on rating and using result to get additional data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to come up with an SQL which gets every

- country's  name,
- code,
- number of games,
- TOP player's name and
- his id
- based on the SUM(rating) in the games table.

I'm having trouble with getting the name of the top player based on the rating.

[image]

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/895b0)

Comment: can you post structure and sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  x.Country AS CountryName,
        x.Code,
        a.totalCount as NumberOfGames,
        y.Name AS PlayersName,
        y.ID AS PlayersID,
        a.totalRating
FROM    (
            SELECT  player_ID, Country, COUNT(*) totalCount, SUM(Rating) totalRating
            FROM    Games
            GROUP BY player_ID, Country
        ) a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Country, Max(totaLRating) maxRating
            FROM
            (
                SELECT  player_ID, Country, SUM(Rating) totalRating
                FROM    Games
                GROUP BY player_ID, Country
            ) s
            GROUP BY Country
        ) b ON a.Country = b.Country AND
                a.totalRating = b.maxRating
        INNER JOIN Country x
            ON a.Country = x.ID
        INNER JOIN Players y
            ON a.player_ID = y.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc0c2/4)

Comment: Sorry for the extra question, but I would like to know what to add to the sql so that I can get a column with the the total sum of the country's rating

Comment: a.totalRating returns the totalRating for the player in this case, which is useful, but i would like to have a sum of the total rating per country, regardless the player. In your case Germany will be 27 totalRating.

Comment: Got it... I had to add SUM(totalRating) as interestAll

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from games inner join players on games.player_id=players.id inner join country on games.country=country.id order by rating desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select 
    c.id as country_id,
    c.name as Country,
    c.code as CCode,
    g.T_Games,
    p.id as Player_id,
    p.name as Player
from country as c
left join (select country , count(country) as T_Games from games group by country) as g on g.country = c.id
left join (select id , country , player_id , max(rating) from games group by country) as gl on gl.country = c.id
left join (select id , name from player) as p on p.id = gl.player_id
```

Here is the demo on sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f74a7/1